# Patch request is not working multipart form data

Tags: php, api

Any idea why PATCH  wouldn't be accepting multipart/form-data file uploads? I am trying to update data using mumultipart form data  but my postman is not recognising variables  If I POST the file, it works fine. following is my function in php

```
function updateImage($writeDB, $returned_userid) {
 
  // Retrieve the record to be updated
  $query = $writeDB->prepare('SELECT users.id, users.name, users.mobilenumber, users.profilepic from users where users.id=:userid');

  $query->bindParam(':userid', $returned_userid, PDO::PARAM_INT);
  $query->execute();

  // get row count
  $rowCount = $query->rowCount();

  // make sure that the user exists for the given ID
  if($rowCount === 0) {
    // send JSON error response using function
    sendResponse(404, false, "No user found to update");
  }

  // for each row returned - should be just one
  while($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $image = new Image($row['id'], null, $row['name'], $row['mobilenumber'], $row['profilepic'], null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null);
  }

  // Update the record
  $name = isset($_POST['name']) ? $_POST['name'] : null;
  $filename = isset($_FILES['image']['name']) ? $_FILES['image']['name'] : null;
  $tmp_name = isset($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']) ? $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'] : null;

  if (!empty($name)) {
     echo $name;
    $image->setProfile($name);
  }

  if (!empty($filename) && !empty($tmp_name)) {
    // Handle the image upload
    move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, "uploads/$filename");
    $image->setProfilePic("uploads/$filename");
  }

  // Update the database record
  $query = $writeDB->prepare("UPDATE users SET profilepic = :profilepic WHERE id = :userid");
  $query->bindParam(':profilepic', $image->getProfilePic());
  $query->bindParam(':userid', $returned_userid, PDO::PARAM_INT);
  $query->execute();

  // Return the updated record
  $record = array(
    "id" => $image->getId(),
    "name" => $image->getUsername(),
    "mobilenumber" => $image->getMobileNo(),
    "profilepic" => $image->getProfilePic()
  );

  header('Content-Type: application/json');
  echo json_encode($record);
}
if(empty($_GET)){
         $returned_userid = checkAuthStatusAndReturnUserID($writeDB);
        switch($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']){
        case 'PATCH':
  
        updateImage($writeDB, $returned_userid);
            break;

    }
    }
```

following is my postman response I am trying to print the name variable but it is always null

[image]

Answer (score 1):

`PATCH` is not for uploading binary data (like what you want with the image), see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/http/methods/patch
(Allowed in HTML Forms: No).

Uploading binary data (like images) has to be done with `POST` always, `PUT` or `PATCH` are used to modify the attributes of the ressorce.

Comment: ya profile pic is the name of image I aim trying to update only name of the image there fore I am trying to update only name not image

Answer (score 1):

You can only retrieve data directly from `$_POST` if the request method is post. Since the request method is `patch` in your case, you can parse the data to `$_POST` like so

```
parse_str(file_get_contents('php://input'), $_POST);
echo $_POST['name']; // now this should work
```